I'm getting the wrong expressions for the thevenin and norton equivalents in this circuit, what am I missing?
I'm suposed to find expressions for V_Th, R_Th, I_N, and R_N, for points a,b. now we know the expressions for the resistances would be the same.
I started by finding V_Th by removing the R_L resistor to leave ab O.C. this way the top dependent current source is also O.C. and no current is supposed to flow through R_1 so we should get a voltage divider meaning \$\frac{V_0R_2}{R_2+R_3}\$ this is correct so far, now to calculate the R_Th, I S.C. the voltage source V_0 and got that the eq resistance is supposed to be \$R_1+R_2||R_3\$ but when I check the answer it says that R_Th is \$R_1(A+1)+R_2||R_3\$
afterward, I tried another method where I forced in between nodes ab a test voltage and did some KCL but even so, I got the wrong answer.
can someone explain how exactly they got the answer and what am I doing wrong?


But did you include the dependent current source when finding I_SC current?

@G36 Yes i did, but still got the wrong answer, though I'm sure some mistakes have been made as the process felt really convoluted

You need to show us your calculations since the professor's answer is correct about Rth.

@G36 I would appreciate it if someone would share their process on how to do so, I was doing it on a whiteboard so I'll hopefully write it tomorrow and share it here

I have a tip for you: To find Rth, replace the Vo source with a short circuit and connect a test current source (I_test) instead of a load resistance. Now, with this simplified schematic try to find V_test (the voltage across the test current source). And the RTH is Rth = V_test/I_test

i'll give this one a try as well, thanks

@G36 thanks! i just did it again with the test current source and got the answer, may I ask why the current source made things way easier than a voltage source?

This is the case because we have a current controlled current source. I encourage you to add your solution so that we all can see it.


First, I will present a method that uses Mathematica to solve this problem. I know that this approach is not 'smart' but this method will work all the time, even when the circuit is (way) more complicated than this one. Also, this method will check your work.

Well, we are trying the analyze the following circuit:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
When we use and apply KCL, we can write the following set of equations:
$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_0+\text{n}\cdot\text{I}_4&=\text{I}_1\\
\\
\text{I}_1+\text{I}_4&=\text{I}_2\\
\\
0&=\text{I}_3+\text{I}_4+\text{n}\cdot\text{I}_4\\
\\
\text{I}_2+\text{I}_3&=\text{I}_0
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag1
$$
When we use and apply Ohm's law, we can write the following set of equations:
$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_1&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_2-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_2-\text{V}_1}{\displaystyle\text{R}_4}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$
Now, we can set up a Mathematica code to solve for all the voltages and currents:
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I0 + n*I4 == I1, I1 + I4 == I2, 0 == I3 + I4 + n*I4, 
   I2 + I3 == I0, I1 == (Vi - V1)/R1, I2 == (V1 - 0)/R2, 
   I3 == (V2 - 0)/R3, I4 == (V2 - V1)/R4}, {I0, I1, I2, I3, I4, V1, 
   V2}]]

Out[1]={{I0 -> (((1 + n) (R2 + R3) + R4) Vi)/(
   R2 (R3 + n R3 + R4) + R1 (R2 + R3 + n R3 + R4)), 
  I1 -> ((R2 + R3 + n R3 + R4) Vi)/(
   R2 (R3 + n R3 + R4) + R1 (R2 + R3 + n R3 + R4)), 
  I2 -> ((R3 + n R3 + R4) Vi)/(
   R2 (R3 + n R3 + R4) + R1 (R2 + R3 + n R3 + R4)), 
  I3 -> ((1 + n) R2 Vi)/(
   R2 (R3 + n R3 + R4) + R1 (R2 + R3 + n R3 + R4)), 
  I4 -> -((R2 Vi)/(R2 (R3 + n R3 + R4) + R1 (R2 + R3 + n R3 + R4))), 
  V1 -> (R2 (R3 + n R3 + R4) Vi)/(
   R2 (R3 + n R3 + R4) + R1 (R2 + R3 + n R3 + R4)), 
  V2 -> ((1 + n) R2 R3 Vi)/(
   R2 (R3 + n R3 + R4) + R1 (R2 + R3 + n R3 + R4))}}

Now, we can find:

\$\text{V}_\text{th}\$ we get by finding \$\text{V}_2-\text{V}_1\$ and letting \$\text{R}_4\to\infty\$:
$$\text{V}_\text{th}=-\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_2\text{V}_\text{i}}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}\tag3$$
\$\text{I}_\text{th}\$ we get by finding \$\text{I}_4\$ and letting \$\text{R}_4\to0\$:
$$\text{I}_\text{th}=-\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_2\text{V}_\text{i}}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\right)\left(1+\text{n}\right)}\tag4$$
\$\text{R}_\text{th}\$ we get by finding:
$$\text{R}_\text{th}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{th}}{\displaystyle\text{I}_\text{th}}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_1\text{R}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}+\text{R}_3\left(1+\text{n}\right)\tag5$$

Where I used the following Mathematica codes:
In[2]:=FullSimplify[
 Limit[(((1 + n) R2 R3 Vi)/(
    R2 (R3 + n R3 + R4) + R1 (R2 + R3 + n R3 + R4))) - ((
    R2 (R3 + n R3 + R4) Vi)/(
    R2 (R3 + n R3 + R4) + R1 (R2 + R3 + n R3 + R4))), R4 -> Infinity]]

Out[2]=-((R2 Vi)/(R1 + R2))

In[3]:=FullSimplify[
 Limit[-((R2 Vi)/(R2 (R3 + n R3 + R4) + R1 (R2 + R3 + n R3 + R4))), 
  R4 -> 0]]

Out[3]=-((R2 Vi)/(R1 R2 + (1 + n) (R1 + R2) R3))

In[4]:=FullSimplify[%2/%3]

Out[4]=(R1 R2)/(R1 + R2) + R3 + n R3

